# Accessing a variable set in a child template from the parent template with Twig

Tags: symfony, templates, inheritance, twig

I have the following setup in my templates. I have numerous child templates like this where the `subject` block is different every time.

Is there a way for me to access the `subjectTitle` variable set in the child from the parent?

Parent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span style="display: none !important;">{{ preHeader }}</span>
```

Child:

```
{% extends 'CRMPiccoMailerBundle:Email:base.html.twig' %}
{% block subject %}
    {% set subjectTitle = 'Thanks for ordering! Your Order is 1872.' %}
    {{ subjectTitle }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you want to access parent variable in child template ? Can you please make it clear... ?

Comment: @NandaKumar No, I am asking "Is there a way for me to access the `subjectTitle` variable set in the child from the parent?". I appreciate this may not be possible, however i'm just trying to determine if that is the case.

Comment: May i Know the reason behind this ? So that everything could understand the theory if it is a new one..

Comment: @NandaKumar I always have the same parent template, however the child template will change regularly. As the child template changes the `subjectTitle` changes too, however I am investigating if it is possible to access that variable from the _parent_ template. See here to see what i'm trying to achieve https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-responsive-email-templates-with-ink#add-a-preheader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of achieving the result you want is by creating an empty `block` on the parent template, then setting it's value at the child template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access the variables like any other variable. Be sure you check if its defined, and flow correctly.

### Example

One way I use the child variables is for style sheets:

#### `base.html.twig`

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link href="css/{{ style|default('base') }}.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if style is not defined %}
        <p>Default style applied</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>Styling!</p>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- content here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `contact.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% set style = 'contact' %}
...
```

In the head section, I used a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#macros) for checking the variable and showing a default value if it was undefined (this only works in version 1.12+). If the child template defines the variable, it will use its value otherwise it defaults to the base style sheet. But in the body I show the older way using [tags](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/index.html#tags). Depending if the variable was defined, decides which paragraph to output.